# How can I display a string with its rational expressions, such as '\'

Tags: python, python-3.x, backslash

I want to display a rational expression using Python 3. Because it is stored in my variable, it applies the effect of the backslash on my terminal, here is the rational expression I try to display :

```
struct = "{}\"{}\"{}{}{}"
```

So what I am trying to find is an expression that prints all the string, including the `'\'`

Comment: Try using a raw string by appending `r` before the opening quote: `struct = r"{}\"{}\"{}{}{}"`.

Comment: What do you  mean by "rational expression"? As defined, your string does not contain any backslashes; they are consumed during the *construction* of the string to escape the double quotes.

Comment: I mean like special characters who have an effect on the string, I kinda confused it with the bash rational expressions. But you are right, I didn't write any backslashes not consumed, all I wanted to do was display the ones who escape the double quote, but now I know that I can do so by typing 'r' just before the opening quote just as said by the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
struct = '{}\\"{}\\"{}{}{}'
```